# Getting "Query Too Complex" error when executing an UPDATE query - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE [Tasks$] SET SPRINT = 1, THEME = "INTEGRATION" WHERE STORY = 1
```

Here's the data set:

```
SPRINT  THEME       STORY   Task        Estimate    Assigned     IN_PROGRESS    DONE
1       INTEGRATION 1       Some task   1           AA           Wed, Feb 6     Wed, Feb 13
```

The Worksheet is called "Tasks".  I'm not sure why this isn't working as the query isn't really too complex and a very similar query is working on another worksheet.  There's a total of 120 rows in the Tasks worksheet.

I receive this error on the Execute method call:

```
Sql = "UPDATE [Tasks$]..."
cn.Execute (Sql)
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

This is how the connection is created.

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
conn.Open
```

Comment: What database product are you connecting too?

Comment: @RBarryYoung It looks like he's using either `DAO` or `ADO` to manipulate data in an excel worksheet, is that right Nightwolf?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with how the connection is created.  Thank you.

Comment: Random thought: did you correctly escape the `"` characters around "INTEGRATION" or replace them with `'` characters instead? Pretty sure this would generate a syntax error rather than the error you are seeing though

Comment: @barrowc - I did try that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Sub test()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    cn.Open

    cn.Execute "UPDATE [Tasks$] SET SPRINT = 1, THEME = ""INTEGRATION"" WHERE STORY = 1"
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

I'm assuming your `conn` and `cn` variable is a just a typo in your post and not in your code. Also, the workbook must be saved first, but I'd think you'd get a whole different error. You should try copying that worksheet to a new workbook and see if the same code works. Then you should try changing the sheet name (and the code to match).

Comment: Thank you.  Copying the same thing into a new workbook did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are exporting more than 32,767 characters for an Excel cell. Because Excel can contain max 32,767 chars. 
https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa